# Embed URL in email

Tags: playframework

Here's my scenario:

1. User registers him/herself to the system.
2. System sends confirmation email
3. User clicks the URL within the email to complete the registration

In the 2nd step, I'm trying to embed "activation" URL(resolved by @@{Controller.action()}) in email.
Email will be sent by custom class extended from Mailer.
I set the "application.baseUrl" for development and production server by reading the following page, which explains application.baseUrl setting.
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#application.baseUrl

(app/views/registerer.txt)

```
Click below to confirm user registration:
@@{Registerer.activateUser(token)}
```

(app/notifiers/MailSender.java)

```
public class MailSender extends Mailer {
    public static void registration(User user, String token) {
        setSubject("User Registration Confirmation"));
        addRecipient(user.email);
        setFrom("XXXSystem <auto-mail@xxxsystem.com>");
        send(user, token);
    }
}
```

(conf/application.conf)

```
application.baseUrl=http://localhost:9000/
%prod.application.baseUrl=http://www.realaddressgoeshere.com/
```

**I would like to get working server's URL, but I get the URL
for development.**

Expecting to get:

```
Click below to confirm user registration:
http://www.realaddressgoeshere.com/registerer/activateuser?token=sometokengoeshere
```

But I get:

```
Click below to confirm user registration:
http://127.0.0.1:9000/registerer/activateuser?token=sometokengoeshere
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are running play behind some web server like apache in production.

By default in play "application.baseUrl" is only used when the Request object is null (when invoking Mail from a Job). Here is the code from the framework

```
String base =  Http.Request.current() == null ? Play.configuration.getProperty("application.baseUrl", "application.baseUrl") : Http.Request.current().getBase();
```

When you call your mail from a Controller, the "Http.Request.current.getBase()" method is called which can be "http://127.0.0.1:9000" in case you are running behind a front server.

Maybe there is some tuning in the server to correctly pass the request. The other possibility is to manually set the base part of the url.

In your MailSender class you can keep the url into a static variable

```
private static String APPLICATION_URL = Play.configuration.getProperty("application.baseUrl");
```

add it in your sent method

```
public class MailSender extends Mailer {
    public static void registration(User user, String token) {
        String applicationUrl = APPLICATION_URL;
        setSubject("User Registration Confirmation"));
        addRecipient(user.email);
        setFrom("XXXSystem <auto-mail@xxxsystem.com>");
        send(user, token, applicationUrl);
    }
}
```

and use it in your mail

```
${applicationUrl}@{Registerer.activateUser(token)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's very clear and easy to understand. Play app is running behind the apache and I'll take the play-side solution that you gave. I'll check the apache-side tuning too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe confusing `application mode` with `framework id`? In the following line in your application conf, `%prod` refers to framework id `prod`. It does not refer to application mode `PROD`.

```
%prod.application.baseUrl=http://www.realaddressgoeshere.com/
```

If you want that setting to be in effect, you have to set the framework id to "prod" with the `play id` command. See [Play framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ids) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still need it, or somebody else has the same issue...

Since you are running behind an Apache server, assuming you are using mod_proxy and ProxyPass directives to proxy the requests to localhost:9000, you can actually retain the original Host line from the incoming request to the proxied host, instead of the localhost:9000 (or whatever hostname you have specified for the ProxyPass directive). For that, add the following directive to your apache2 VirtualHost config:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

For more information take a look at the [Apache documentation for ProxyPreserveHost Directive here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost).